# C# переопределение ToString

Tags: c#

Читал книгу и увидел такой пример кода:

```
public class Man 
{
   public string Name;
   public override string ToString() => Name;
}
...
Man p = new Man { Name = "Piter" };
Console.WriteLine (p);     //Piter
```

Непонятно, при чем тут `ToString` вообще и почему нам выводит имя при простом вызове экземпляра без указания поля?

Comment: "... вызове экземпляра"? В консоль выводится строковое представление объекта, которое получается вызовом виртуального метода `ToString`.

Comment: то есть я могу внутри метода переназначить ToString и указать, что он будет делать при вызове. И при каждом вызове p (не`p.name` и не `p.ToSrting()` ) у меня будет выводиться именно то, что было определено внутри  `public override string ToString() => Name;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно документации для метода [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Если переданное значение равно `null`, печатается только перевод
>   строки. Иначе, печаетается результат вызова функции `ToString`

`ToString` переопределен таким образом, чтобы выводить поле `Name`, поэтому оно и печатается при вызове `WriteLine`

Comment: аа, понятно.. Жаль, что в учебнике об этом ни слова.. Надо было сразу подумать о документации, спасибо)

Comment: @Nikolay учебник наверное не особо хороший. Ознакомьтесь со списком [литературы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0).

Comment: @alexolut C# 6.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка Албахари читаю) ну мне в любом случае одной книгой не обойтись)

Comment: @Nikolay, когда не понимаете что происходит, полезно заглядывать в исходный код вызываемого метода.

Answer (score 4):

Удалим строку:

```
public override string ToString() => Name;
```

Тогда, при вызове:

```
Console.WriteLine (p);
```

Мы увидим, что то вроде:

```
>>Yournamespace.Man
```

Что не очень информативно, особенно если таких объектов несколько. Это происходит, потому что наследуемая функция [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), выводит полное наименование класса. Если же вам надо, чтобы ВЕЗДЕ, где класс будет отображаться на строку, было другое поведение, надо эту функцию переопределить. Что и было сделано в вышеуказанной строке.

Comment: он выедет название типа в виде строки, как я понимаю. Тогда какой смысл имеют функция `GetType`?

Comment: ее использовать разумней, так как она выполняет свое назначение. Я понимаю. И при переопределении `ToString` не вызовет ошибки. Но без определения ее можно опустить? Вопрос для общего понимания

Comment: 1. `GetType` возвращает [тип](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) класса а не строковое значение его имени, хотя и имя таким образом можно получить.

Comment: 2. Естественно ее можно не переопределять, если для поведения класса не важно что она выдает.